# ActionBar custom don't delete my tradicional ActionBar

Tags: android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I've customized my ActionBar, but when I run the app, I can see the tradicional icon of android and the name of the app and, in 1 second after, I can see my customice ActionBar.

Somebody know, how can I do to fix this error and only show my custom ActionBar??

This is my oncreate in Main:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rellenarNoticias();

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);

        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }
```

This is my custom xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionBarLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/myImage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` to your styles.xml.

If you have multiple styles.xml (For v11 and v14) then set for them as well.